# AWR Report - Tuning Database

Tags: oracle-11g, database-tuning

We have an OLTP system, following are our AWR reports taken during peak hour window for three days once each day. We see a lot of direct path reads; we want to add more PGA in-order to reduce wait time on this wait event. Following is the current setting in our 11g db.

```
Sqls order by cpu

CPU Time (s) Executions  CPU per Exec (s) %Total Elapsed Time (s) %CPU %IO SQL Id SQL Module SQL Text 
7,279.38 9,694 0.75 31.50 7,297.79 99.75 0.27 0dp0c8wux0jnt    select case when max(LMA.LEAS... 
6,562.18 1,395 4.70 28.40 6,582.28 99.69 0.31 3g2kw67v3v0qs    SELECT NAME, vpd_predicates.ge... 
4,229.12 836,735 0.01 18.30 4,234.99 99.86 0.00 55a17fhdqg315 DBMS_SCHEDULER  begin :con := SELECT_POLICY_FU... 
2,683.17 968 2.77 11.61 2,605.03 103.00 7.61 dfd3gcuamscs8    select sc.Doc_ID docId , sc.DO... 
2,434.46 853,025 0.00 10.54 2,442.95 99.65 0.00 4y5m5y6y6wvzs DBMS_SCHEDULER  SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CONTACT_... 


Top 5 Timed Foreground Events 08-Feb-2011
Event   Waits   Time(s) Avg wait (ms)   % DB time   Wait Class
DB CPU      23,108      94.74    
db file sequential read 1,332,461   797 1   3.27    User I/O
direct path read    430,600 523 1   2.14    User I/O
db file scattered read  245,444 224 1   0.92    User I/O
SQL*Net more data to client 2,057,853   155 0   0.64    Network
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that something like 95% of your wait time is on CPU.  Even if you completely eliminated the direct path reads, you'd eliminate less than 2% of your total wait time.  It seems unlikely that a 2% reduction in your wait time would even register as an improvement.

Taking a look at what is consuming all that CPU-- you have a handful of very CPU intensive queries. 0dp0c8wux0jnt and 3g2kw67v3v0qs are consuming 60% of the CPU your system is using. Have you looked at optimizing those queries so that they use less CPU? 3g2kw67v3v0qs in particular takes nearly 5 seconds per execution.

What else do you have running on this machine?  A total SGA & PGA that is 6% of the memory available on the machine implies that you probably have a number of other things running (perhaps many database instances).

Comment: Thanks Justin,following is order by cpu time.09-Feb-2011
CPU Time (s) Executions  CPU per Exec (s) %Total Elapsed Time (s) %CPU %IO SQL Id SQL Module SQL Text
9,453.92 10,511 0.90 35.93 9,466.79 99.86 0.15 0dp0c8wux0jnt
   select case when max(LMA.LEAS...
8,698.59 1,553 5.60 33.06 8,714.06 99.82 0.17 3g2kw67v3v0qs
   SELECT NAME, vpd_predicates.ge...
4,805.17 960,387 0.01 18.26 4,816.80 99.76 0.00 55a17fhdqg315
DBMS_SCHEDULER  begin :con := SELECT_POLICY_FU...
2,872.26 1,047 2.74 10.92 2,693.38 106.64 5.95 dfd3gcuamscs8
   select sc.Doc_ID docId , sc.DO...
2,711.61 980,593 0.00 10.31 2,715.21

Comment: @Sreedhar - Can you add that to your question (and use the formatting options to keep things lined up)?

Comment: Justin,I coudnt really format it.please paste this to notepad CPU Time (s)Executions CPUperExec(s) %Total ElapsedTime(s) %CPU %IO 4,679.00 8,106 0.58 21.84 4,703.85 99.47 0.57 4,040.80 1,437 2.81 18.86 4,067.93 99.33 0.69 3,797.96 761,428 0 17.73 3,805.93 99.79 0 3,129.01 1,191 2.63 14.61 2,978.27 105.06 5.81 2,141.68 778,900 0 10 2,149.43 99.64 0

Comment: @Sreedhar - If you post unformatted text, we can't just copy it to notepad, it's already lost all of the formatting.  If you edit your question to post unformatted text, we can at least edit it to insert a small amount of formatting like we did with your initial question.  Editing your question to add formatted text would be best though.

Comment: OK.  So you have some very CPU intensive queries.  0dp0c8wux0jnt     and 3g2kw67v3v0qs are consuming 60% of the CPU your system is using.  Have you looked at optimizing those queries so that they use less CPU?  3g2kw67v3v0qs in particular takes nearly 5 seconds per execution.

Comment: Yes,we are going to tune those top sqls,apart from that..we are thinking of increasing SGA to reduce the sequential read waits and increase the PGA to reduce direct path read waits even though both have less than 4% db time. reading from forums some people suggesting that in any OLTP system PGA should be higher than SGA is this true?? Increasing SGA and PGA cause any damage to system?? Pleae advice..

Comment: There is certainly no rule that the PGA should be larger than the SGA in an OLTP system.  Generally, OLTP systems will devote most of their RAM to SGA with a couple MB per session of PGA because most OLTP queries are doing single row lookups not large sorts.  But your system could well be different.  It doesn't seem to make sense to me to try to tune operations that are, at most, 5% of your database time-- even if you eliminated all waits for physical I/O, you'd eliminate at most 5% of your waits-- it's unlikely that would matter.

Comment: Thanks Justin for your inputs., our queries run faster but executed thousands of times in a day.Our env uses oracle VPD functionality to enforce rules,so,every time table listed in the policy queried predicate is determined on the runtime and applied, determining predicate is one of our top sqls, query(0dp0c8wux0jnt) is executed almost one million times in a day and it is consuming 32% cpu.we can not avoid number of executions..and query comes back in less than 1sec..we dont know what to do now.. so,we thought of increasing SGA and PGA or add more CPUs would help us..

Comment: I see no evidence that adjusting the memory structures would meaningfully influence performance.  Depending on what else is running on the machine, it seems odd that this database is using only 6% of the available RAM (that information has been removed from your question unfortunately) so it's not unreasonable to consider adjusting the memory-- it just won't improve your current performance.  If you can add additional physical CPUs, that has a much greater probability of improving things.  I'd strongly suggest digging in to those queries, though, to see where they can be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Direct path read is a classic symptom of parallel full table scans - what's your top SQL by I/O? I'd look at the query plan for that to make sure an index is being used. What's your parallelism set to?

Upping the PGA will only help if it's *one* session doing all of those for a given table, in the worst case each session will need a PGA large enough to cache the entire table...

Comment: Thanks Gaius..We dont enforce any parallelism,our queries run faster but executed thousands of times in a day.Our env uses oracle VPD functionality to enforce rules,so,every time table listed in the policy queried,predicate is determined on the runtime and applied, determining predicate is one of our top sqls, gui users complaining slowness..

Comment: Am I reading correctly that there is 48G of RAM in this box, but you are only using 2G SGA? Is the box doing something else as well? If so that AWR report won't be telling the whole truth. If not, up your SGA to 24G and see what happens. I have some systems with 30G SGAs on 48G boxes. That will cut your sequential reads hopefully...

Answer (score 1):

There's wait event enq: TM - contention. This wait event occurs when you have unindexed foreign key constrained column(s). An update on the master table will lock entire child table.
I have a query which generate create index statement for the missing indices. You may change the naming conventions to your favor.

```
SELECT 'CREATE INDEX '||a.owner||'.IX_'||a.table_name||'__'||
    replace(a.column_name, 'FK_', '') ||' ON '||a.owner||'.'||a.table_name||
    ' ('||a.column_name||') LOGGING TABLESPACE '||
    replace(b.tablespace_name, '_DAT', '_IDX')||' NOPARALLEL ONLINE;
/'
FROM (
   SELECT c.owner, c.table_name, cc.column_name, cc.position column_position
   FROM   all_constraints c, all_cons_columns cc
   WHERE  c.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name and c.owner=cc.owner
   AND    c.constraint_type = 'R'
   MINUS
   SELECT i.owner, i.table_name, ic.column_name, ic.column_position
   FROM   all_indexes i, all_ind_columns ic
   WHERE  i.index_name = ic.index_name and i.owner=ic.index_owner
) a
inner join all_tables b on b.owner=a.owner and b.table_name=a.table_name
where a.owner='<owner>'
ORDER BY a.owner, a.table_name, a.column_position;
```

Comment: We have identiified this and fix is going into prod soon,Thank you.